# can't ssh to docker container of jenkinsci/ssh-slave

Tags: jenkins, ssh, docker

I'm using the docker image of [jenkinsci/ssh-slave](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-slave)
First I generated a key on my machine:

```
ssh-keygen
```

I paste the content of my public key in my docker run command so it looks like:

```
$ docker run jenkinsci/ssh-slave "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADA.."
```

When the container is running I try to connect (as root user and as jenkins user). First I need to get the container IP:

```
$ docker inspect 65ebc0f67879 | grep IP

172.17.0.x
```

I try to ssh:

```
$ ssh -i id_rsa root@172.17.0.x
```

But `Permission denied (publickey).`
What am I doing wrong?
When I `exec` the container I see my public key in the `authorized_keys`:

```
cat /home/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

content:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADA..
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to login as the user "jenkins":

```
ssh -i id_rsa jenkins@172.17.0.x
```

The relevant lines of code are here:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-slave/blob/master/Dockerfile#L27
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-slave/blob/master/setup-sshd#L32

Answer (score 1):

If you try as user jenkins then you'll get the error : Permission denied (publickey).

/home/jenkins/.ssh has the right permissions but wrong ownership.

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Nov 21 10:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Mar 31  2017 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  220 Nov  5  2016 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 3515 Nov  5  2016 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  675 Nov  5  2016 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Nov 21 09:55 .ssh
```

I tried to change that by updating my Dockerfile with the command

```
RUN chown -Rf jenkins:jenkins "${JENKINS_AGENT_HOME}/.ssh"
```

and owner:group ain't changed (possibly entrypoint.sh overrides it)

```
Step 7/12 : COPY ./ssh/authorized_keys /home/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fb76b6c80648
 Step 8/12 : RUN chmod 600 /home/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys
 ---> Running in c76f24a8e2d8
 ---> 2e2398ccd53c
Step 9/12 : RUN chmod 700 /home/jenkins/.ssh
---> Running in 22e4983555bb
---> 9ac1d7055294
Step 10/12 : RUN chown -Rf jenkins:jenkins "${JENKINS_AGENT_HOME}/.ssh"
---> Running in 1636f6f08bdf
---> 58f5679f90f5
Step 11/12 : RUN ls -al /home/jenkins/
---> Running in 51fe02e603df
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Nov 21 10:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Mar 31  2017 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  220 Nov  5  2016 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 3515 Nov  5  2016 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  675 Nov  5  2016 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Nov 21 09:55 .ssh
---> 997f3401475c
Step 12/12 : COPY ./resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
---> f5111f5dec09
```

I had no luck with that so I used images environment variable
`docker run -e "JENKINS_SLAVE_SSH_PUBKEY=<public key>" my-slave`

And, hey! It Worked!

Solution: Build your own jenkins slave by using a base image that makes you feel comfortable with.